WPF: Long-running task running in a new thread fails to respond to UI's stop signal
This is a signal acquisition program where getDataEx is used to collect signals. When the start button is clicked in WPF, getDataEx function runs in a background thread, and the collected data is displayed correctly on the UI. However, clicking the stop button has no effect.
//C++ code
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void getDataEx(void (*funcptr)(short), WORD wPeriod, DWORD data_count, bool& stopSignal);
void getDataEx(void (*funcptr)(short), WORD wPeriod, DWORD data_count, bool& stopSignal)
{
    ...
    while (data_count > 0 && !stopSignal)
    {
        Sleep(dwdelayTime);
        data_count--;
        ...
    }
}

//C# WPF
[DllImport("*.dll")]
private extern static void getDataEx(DataCallback funcPtr, ushort wPeriod, uint data_count, ref bool stopSignal);
private bool stopSignal = false;
private void StartDataAcquisition()
{
    if (isScan && isOpen)
    {
        dataAcquisitionThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            // Define the callback function in C#
            DataCallback callbackFunction = (value) =>
            {
                float pressure_value = (float)(value / 65535.0 * 10);
                // Update the UI on the main thread
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    ...
                });
            };
            getDataEx(callbackFunction, wPeriod, sample_times, ref stopSignal);
        });
        dataAcquisitionThread.Start();
    }
}
//stop

private void btn_stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    stopSignal = true;
}

If I set stopSignal = true; before running the getDataEx function, the stopSignal can be passed to the getDataEx function.

Side note : do NOT combine a sleep with a boolean stop flag. Use a std::condition_variable that waits for the sleep time OR the flag.  In general having sleeps in your code is a bad practice.

I also would model a stop as a seperate call so you don't have to pass a reference from C# to C++. The garbage collector might move the C# object around in memory invalidating your reference. Read about "pinning" .Net memory if you'd like to know moere.  Another bit of advice : stop using "dllimport" and switch to C++/cli (managed C++ code) and write a small interop layer in C++/cli (instead of the extern "C")

create a CancellationToken and turn the Method into an Async Task , use the CancellationToken you create such if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) ... then ( do this and this ) 
